# Laravel NotFoundHttpException Handling

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am Unable to handle *NotFoundHttpException* in Laravel

I have already tried to handle it through **render()** in Handler.php

```php
// Handler.php 
// render()
==============

public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
            return response('Not Found');
        }
        return parent::render($request,$e);
   }
```

It should return the response 'Not Found'. But it is returning

> Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'
>   not found

Which means that NotFoundHttpException class cannot be found in vendor folder, I tried to look for the class in the path specified but I could not find it.

Comment: When adding use Exception;  what error you are getting?

Answer (score 5):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? If that class had not been imported, how should the error message print the FQDN?

Answer (score 4):

You can try it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
            switch ($statusCode) {
                case '404':
                    return response()->view('errors/404');
                case '500';
                    return response()->view('errors/500');
            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

}
```

Merge this code in your handler.php instead of pasting it directly.

Answer (score 1):

**write in top of controller**

```
use Exception;
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? If `Exception` had not been imported properly, there should be another error message

Answer (score 1):

In handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
                case 404:
                    return redirect()->route('error404');
                    break;
                case '500':
                    return redirect()->route('error500');
                    break;
                default:
                    return redirect()->route('errordefault');
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            return parent::render($request,$exception);
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

And then in web.php you can route to your desire Controller, here I have handled with self made ErrorController.php

```
//Error page
Route::get('errors', 'ErrorController@errordefault')->name('errordefault');
Route::get('404', 'ErrorController@error404')->name('error404');
Route::get('500', 'ErrorController@error500')->name('error500');
```

Make function errordefault(), error404() and error500() in ErrorController;

In ErrorController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ErrorController extends Controller
{

    public function error404()
    {
        return view('error_page');
    }
    public function error500()
    {
        return view('error500_page');
    }
    public function errordefault()
    {
        return view('default_error_page');
    }
}
```

Comment: its not the problem of redirection , the if condition is returning false always due to which the body of if statement is not executed in Handler.php.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in laravel

```
     try{
        $response= model::where('uid',$uid)->update($insertArry);
        if($response){
            $backMessage = "insert success";
            $status='success';
            return redirect()->route('website')->with($status, $backMessage);

        }else{
            $backMessage = "something wrong！";
            $status='danger';
            return redirect()->route('website')->with($status, $backMessage);
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        //get exception here
        $backMessage = $e;
        $status='info';
        return redirect()->route('website')->with($status, $backMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dd($excpetion);
Sometimes is another exception like
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
app>Exception>Handler.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

Just put the below code under the register method

```
   $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) { 
           // Here *api* is route prefix just validate your route 
           // also you can use withot checking the request but it's not good

           // If you want you can return view or json response from here 
            return response()->view('errors.invalid-order', [], 500);
           // Or
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Record not found.'
            ], 404);
        }
    });
```